# I have a problem with std::unique (algorithm) C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

I have a problem with finding 2 minimal numbers. I am getting a wrong output.

Example:

- Input: `{-1, 2, 5, 3, 8, -1, 3, 5, 0}`
- Output: `{-1, -1}`
- Right answer: `{-1, 2}`

I believe that there is a problem with `unique` because it doesn't delete all same numbers.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Following is my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

void input(std::vector<int> &vec) {
    int num;
    std::cin >> num;
    if (num == 0){
        return;
    }
    
    vec.push_back(num);

    return input(vec);
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec;
    input(vec);

    unique(vec.begin(), vec.end()); // It doesnt work correctly

    std::vector<int>::iterator it = min_element(vec.begin(), vec.end());
    std::cout << "\n" << *it << " ";
    vec.erase(it);

    it = min_element(vec.begin(), vec.end());
    std::cout << *it << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::unique` removes duplicates only when they are consecutive. Here a simple `for` loop could find the second minimum

Comment: Decent documentation clearly states what you missed. For example, [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique): "_Eliminates all except the first element from every **consecutive group of equivalent elements**_". For the unique elements to be consecutive, the range must first be sorted.

Comment: I don't understand how right answer should be `{-1, 2}`, (-1 < 0 < 2)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array needs to be sorted for `unique` to work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

@Mikhail, answered your question. However, if you sort then use `std::unique`, you will be doing more work than you need to.

You can actually solve this problem with a lower complexity with just a single loop across the collection, finding the two smallest unique values. I haven't checked the code below compiles, but it would go something like this.

```
#include <numeric>
#include <utility>
#include <limits>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

pair<int, int> find_2_min_values(const vector<int>& collection)
{
    assert(collection.size() > 1);
    auto res = make_pair(numeric_limits<int>::max(),
                         numeric_limits<int>::max());
    
    for (const auto& i : collection)
    {
        if (i < res.first)
            res.first = i;
        else if (i < res.second)
            res.second = i; 
    }

    return res;
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> col = {-1, 2, 5, 3, 8, -1, 3, 5, 0};    
    auto res = find_2_min_values(col);

    cout << "first: " << res.first << "\n" 
         << "second: " << res.second << endl;
}
```

There are some edge cases this will not handle correctly, an example being a collection in descending order.